# when overwrite complex object key in a map, will old object got deleted (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdmap

I have a map of `<MyObject, int>` to count the occurrences of each instances. Upon overwrite key myObject1 with an equal myObject2, will myObject1 got deleted and memory allocated to myObject1 got recovered?

for example I have text file that consist of name, gender, age, height, of people. Assuming I just want to count how many unique (name, gender) pairs. So I create my Person (string name, int gender) objects, and add it to a std::map (let's say I have to use map instead of set)

```
std::map<Person, int> myMapCounter;
//for each line
  Person newperson(name, gender);
  myMapCounter[newperson] = 1 ;// just a dummy value 
//end for 

int number = myMapCounter.size();
```

upon creating a new Person object that is equal to old one from previous line, will `myMapCounter[newperson] = 1` delete the old object (recover memory, so there is only 1 block of memory for this certain "person") , or the "old" object will still exist in the memory?

Comment: Map stores copies of it's keys. And those copies are only exposed as `const`. You cannot change the key of a map element.

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Weird question. Keys are compared using `compare` function. If older and newer equally compares to true, then that means that the key is already there, so there is no need for replacement of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it worked for me when implemented an `operator <` function.
The key in the `std::map` is queried for its < with the other one when wanting to add

When you are wanting to add a `Person` struct/class to your map, it is queried with others is it < or not.

Trying code like that to see what really happens

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string gender;
public:
    Person(std::string name, std::string gender): name(name), gender(gender) {}
    Person(const Person &person): name(person.name), gender(person.gender) {}
    inline std::string getName() const { return name; }
    inline std::string getGender() const { return gender; }
    friend bool operator <(const Person &first, const Person &other);
};

inline bool operator <(const Person &first, const Person &other)
{
    std::cout << "Comparing " << first.name << " with " << other.name << "\n";
    if (first.name == other.name) {
        return first.gender < other.gender;
    } else {
        return first.name < other.name;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::map<Person, int> map;
    map[Person("One", "male")] = 1;
    map[Person("Two", "male")] = 4;
    map[Person("A", "male")] = 3;
    std::cout << "Ending adding\n";
    std::cout << map[Person("One", "male")];
}
```

You would see something like that

```
Comparing Two with One
Comparing One with Two
Comparing A with One
Ending adding
Comparing One with One
Comparing One with One
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do have '<' operator. My question was about the creation / deletion of objects. From @François Andrieux 's comment, I guess there would be : 
1) 1 creation of object (named newperson) 
2) a copy to map container
3) a deletion of the newperson object as it goes out of the for loop scope. 
In the end, there will be only unique objects in the memory (in the map container as keys)

Comment: It is a value type, not a reference type, this is C++ not Java.   So I think when you make a `map[Person("One", "male")]`, you create a "temporary variable", that could enter the function,  the function compare the inner values with the value passed in,  then the value passed in is deleted when not used again by the caller scope,  but I think as a C++ optimization, this object wouldn't be created, I think it would be optimized to a "pass by value" thing